# How to properly traverse tree and parse text file?

Tags: python, list

I am having trouble with my code below.

I am trying to walk the directories and parse the `.txt` files encountered.
Any line that begins with a number should be parsed and added to a nested
list.

Currently my nested lists contain the parsed contents from all of the files instead
of individual files.

Example:

> I have 2 text files with 2 lines each, text file 1 contains numbers 11 and 12 in lines 1 and 2, and text file 2 contains numbers 21 and 22 in lines 1 and 2.

When my text files are parsed my result is:

```
[['11', '12', '21', '22'], ['11', '12', '21', '22'],['11', '12', '21', '22'],['11', '12', '21', '22']]
```

I would like to have:

```
[['11', '12'], ['21', '22']]
```

Code below:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
    print(file)
    if file.endswith(".txt")
       os.chdir(os.path.join(root))
       'print(os.getcwd())'
       for line in open(file):
           if line:
              new_line = line.strip()
              'print(new_line)'
              if new_line and new_line.isdigit():
                 line_list.append(new_line)
    list_of_line_lists.append(line_list)
```

Comment: Post code and not images.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please update the question and put your code directly inside the question not an image.

Comment: search for 'python glob'

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Paul, I would like to get my code snippet to work. Maybe my title isn't worded well... I am in a hurry this morning, and I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Each time you open a new file, you should also reset `line_list` to be a new, empty list: `line_list=[]` otherwise you are working with *one* and the same list which gets referenced multiple times in the result list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import os


def main(basedir):
    ll = []  # the list of lists
    for root, _, files in os.walk(basedir):  # walk the base directory
        for f in files:  # for each file
            if f.endswith('.txt'):  # are we interested
                # it's possible that we may not be able to open the file
                # also, its contents may be unmanageable
                try:
                    # open the file - readonly and text mode are default
                    with open(os.path.join(root, f)) as txt:
                        mm = []  # array of values for this file
                        for line in txt:
                            try:
                                # note that there's no need to strip() because of the way int() works
                                v = int(line)
                                # we got a valid int so add it to the list
                                mm.append(v)
                            except ValueError:
                                pass  # couldn't parse the line so ignore it
                        if len(mm) > 0:  # do we have anything to add to the list of lists
                            ll.append(mm)  # yes
                except Exception:
                    pass  # something went wrong with either opening or parseing the file - ignore
    print(ll)  # let's see what we got


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('/Users/yourname/textfiles')
```

Comment: Thank you Andy, I was able to use your example to get my code to work.